# Select Query with ID and Last Date Validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

table 1:

```
ID LastDate

001 20090101
003 20090501
004 20090302
...
```

table2:

```
ID Date Value

001 20090101 100
001 20090102 200
001 20090103 200
002 20090101 350
002 20090302 500
003 20090501 200
003 20090502 250
004 20090302 400
...
```

From the table2 I want to Select id and date, date should display from next date onwards from table1.

Query like:

```
Select * from table2 where date > table1.last on table1.id = table2.id
```

Expected Output:

```
ID Date Value

001 20090102 200
001 20090103 200
002 20090101 350
002 20090302 500
003 20090502 250
...
```

From the above output,

```
id 001 is displaying from the next date of table1.lastdate
id 002 is displaying the same date because 002 is not in table1
id 003 is displaying from the next date of table1.lastdate
id 004 is not displaying because the same date is available on table1.lastdate
```

I want to make a query for the above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
Select * from table2 t2 where t2.date > (select max(date) from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Edited:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t2.Date > 
(
    SELECT ISNULL(maxdate, 0) FROM 
    (
        SELECT MAX(t1.Date) as maxdate FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
    ) t
)
```

Comment: I cannot equal table1.id = table2.id, bcoz table2.id all should diplay even the same id is not in available table1 also..

Comment: so it's a little bit more complicated :) Check this out (I've edited the answer). I have no idea if there's a more simple query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an anti-join is what you need here. You could implement an anti-join, for instance, with `LEFT JOIN` & `IS NULL` check:

```
SELECT
  t2.columns
FROM table2 t2
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date <= t1.Date
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Another way to do the same would be to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
  columns
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NO EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Date <= t1.Date
)
```